# SDL RenderTextShaded Transparent Background

Tags: c++, c, sdl

any Idea how I could have the follow code output text with a transparent background?

```
SDL_Color co = {tp->col.r, tp->col.g, tp->col.b,tp->col.a};
SDL_Color bco = {255, 0, 255,1};
ts = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(tp->font, text.c_str(),co,bco);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TTF_RenderText_Shaded` doesn't allow for transparent backgrounds (as it uses 8bit color), you want to use [`TTF_RenderText_Blended`](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_51.html#SEC51), see [this](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_42.html#SEC42).

Comment: Nice. I had ended up using solid and colorkeying it to transparent, but this seems a lot more elegant.